# File upload destination

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload, upload

I am a bit confused about how a File Upload works.

Assuming I have a simple HTML Form that upload a file to Web Server 2, so:

```
<form action="http://webserver2/index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select image to upload:
   <input type="file" id="file">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

As you can see the form action points to "webserver2" so the file data will get received and read from Web Server 2, which will be able to save the file.

[image]

Question:
Is the file upload directly to Web Server 2 or passing through Web Server 1 first?

My need is: uploading the file to Web Server 2 but retaining a copy on Web Server 1. Is this possible / already happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action field of a `<form>` element tells the browser exactly where to send the contents of that form. As a result of this, the form will be sent directly to Web Server 2, and once it has served the original HTML, Web Server 1 is not involved in the later form submission (as coded in the displayed HTML anyway).

Your best bet for storing the file on Web Server 1 is to have Web Server 2 send it there (this will be best), or perhaps use a shared file system between the two (a lot harder to maintain and not particularly recommended).

Comment: Thank you...I hoped in another solution but it seems to be the only way.